# wp_enqueue_script doesn't load into my template

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add and load my scripts in a safe way. However, when the code is added to functions.php, nothing happens on the specific template.

```
<?php
function theme_scripts() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery',     'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery2', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.easing.1.3.js',     'jquery' );
}    

add_action('init', 'theme_scripts');
?>
```

http://sandbox.jinoh.dk/charlotte/wordpress/wordpress/

I have read that it should be loaded into the template - index.php for example, like a normal  etc, but there is nothing. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `wp_head()` in the header?

Comment: No, I forgot. Silly me, it's past midnight. Slap me for one stupid question. Thank you :) Answer and get the point? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to call `wp_head()` in your theme, typically in your `header.php` file.

This checklist is excellent: [WordPress Theme Development Checklist](http://www.wplover.com/lab/theme-development-checklist/)

Comment: Thank you again. I normally do this, but was sleeping :)